# Can set containing not only all ordinal numbers exist?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I've always seen the same proof of non-existence of set of all ordianal numbers.

It was based on a fact that such a set would fit into definition of ordinal number, and the set itself would be an ordinal number, which would not be included in the set.

Let $d_{'}$, be arbitrary mathematical object which is not an ordinal number.

Then let set $O$ to contain all ordinal numbers and the $d_{'}$ element.

Now the original proof has no problem with $O$, because it contains another element than ordinal number, thus can't be considered one.

Can set such as $O$, exist in for e.g. ZFC?

Comment: Definable subcollections of sets are sets.

Answer (score 2):

If $O$ exists then so does
$$\{\,x\in O\mid x\text{ is an ordinal}\,\}, $$
which does not.

Comment: Why does that have to be the case?

Even if O didn't exist, you could still write
$$\{\,x\mid x\text{ is an ordinal}\,\}, $$
and you would still have syntax describing non-existent set.

Comment: The subset axiom only lets you specify elements coming from an already known set. Thus, you can't specify over all sets, whereas you can specify over all ordinals (if the ordinals form a set).

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you.

Comment: But then, what about set of all ordinal numbers without $1$?

Again, such a set isn't considered an ordinal number, thus it still is okay considering the original proof.

Comment: @Punga Take a look at any book containing the basic axioms of set theory (or even Wikipedia!), and think about them for a few minutes. All variants you are suggesting are completely straightforward, and the fact that you are asking them suggests you are not familiar with the axioms.

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure it's provable in ZF that no set contains all ordinal numbers. I don't know how to write a formal proof in ZF. The axiom schema of specification is not a meaningful statement in ZF and is something more like a rule of inference.